# Some cassandra nodes in cluster are unreachable even all the nodes are up and running

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, jmx, cluster-computing, reachability

I have cassandra cluster of 6 nodes on ec2 , Many times i have observed that all the nodes in the cluster are up and running but when i do the describe cluster from client it shows some nodes as unreachable.

1. I can login to individual machines
2. can connect to cassandra node with cassandra client
3. can connect to individual nodes with JMX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like you have listen_address/broadcast_address misconfigured.

Comment: no ,actually it works most of the time ,but sometimes this problem comes in a picture ,and i need to restart all unreachable nodes and then it works properly

Answer (score 0):

I' am using hector as Cassandra client - maybe you have similar problem.

On `CassandraHost` you can configure `ExhaustedPolicy`. Default, if Cassandra is busy, such host will be marked as down - even if it is online. Hector checks all hosts marked as down every `retryDownedHostsDelayInSeconds`.

Is is possible, that your host was busy for some time, it was marked down, and retry was not triggered yet?